# arcpy array: trouble with reassigning inf to 0

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, numpy

I've converted rasters to arrays via arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray() then divided them by 1. Some resulting values are zero and I need to reassign them after the division to zero. The array types are float64.

I've tried quite a bit of versions of the following code (from other SE searches assigning zero to infinity though) without luck. Any advice?

```
array = array[array == float("inf")] = 0

TypeError: 'float' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about numpy.isinf?

```
array[np.isinf(array)] = 0
```

Comment: okay, maybe it wasn't working because i was defining it twice? a = a[np.isinf(a)] = 0 instead of just a[np.isinf(a)] = 0?